# how get Selected <li> and put it in the top list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I created a multi-language page using unordered list.

I want when the visitor select his language, it becomes the first `li` in list.

```
<div id="lang">
    <ul id="ul">
        <li class="top" id="ar">
            <a href="index.php?lang=ar"><img src="images/languages/eg.png"/>Arabic</a>
        </li>
        <li id="en">
            <a href="index.php?lang=en"><img src="images/languages/us.png"/>English</a>
        </li>
        <li id="fr">
            <a href="index.php?lang=fr"><img src="images/languages/fr.png"/>French</a>
        </li>
        <li id="de">
            <a href="index.php?lang=ge"><img src="images/languages/de.png"/>Germany</a>
        </li>
        <li id="tu">
            <a href="index.php?lang=tu"><img src="images/languages/tr.png"/>Turkey</a>
        </li>
        <li id="cn">
            <a href="index.php?lang=tu"><img src="images/languages/cn.png"/>China</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: even better http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Read through the jQuery documentation, find the method that does exactly what you want (it exists, I promise), then apply it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#lang').on('click', 'li a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ul').prepend($(this).parent());
});
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codepic/MDR6w/1/

I suggest you read the relevant documentation:

1. [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
2. [jQuery event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
3. [jQuery .parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
4. [jQuery .prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

And then there is this performance aspect also. Probably not THAT relevant in this particular example, but it never hurts starting to look into it in the early phase. Plus many times, the best performing code is the code that is simple. And simple also translates many times to "readable".

I took some time to do some performance testing with the examples provided here:

- [jsPerf Tests](http://jsperf.com/how-get-selected-li-and-put-it-in-the-top-list)

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as this:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

See working example here http://jsfiddle.net/NyxnJ/10/

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you can omit .remove()

Comment: @JaniHyytiainen... Yes we can... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('#ul li a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var lielement=$(this).parent('li')
      lielement.remove();
      $('#ul').prepend(lielement);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:  **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AQCx3/1/)**

```
$('div#lang').on('click', 'li:not(:first) a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var li =  $(this).parent();
  li.siblings().removeClass("top").end().prependTo(li.parent()).addClass('top');
  return false;
});
```